# magic keyboard keys started typing wrong characters

Tags: keyboard

I have a magic keyboard with numeric pad bought in 2019, since few days ago :

- the left command key suddenly started to output command and tild at the same time making the key unusable for copy pasting as a tild will always be preprend to the pasted text
- the 9 character on the numberic pads now maps to command. I verified using keyboard viewer that the key 9 do show as triggering the command key.

Any idea what is going on ? My Mac Book Air keyboard work properly, only the magic keyboard with numeric pad has these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it started malfunctioning but I found a workaround so I don't need to buy a new keyboard.

It is possible to detect the real key press triggered on OSX by the physical key press ( which in my case is different than the key it is supposed to trigger ) by using Key Codes from Many Tricks which is available on the Mac appstore ( https://apps.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12 )
It is possible to remap the key press by using an open source software called Karabiner element ( https://github.com/pqrs-org/Karabiner-Elements )

In my case :

- my left command key was triggering f18 according to Key Codes, so under Karabiner I added an item in the simple modifications tab that maps f18 => left_command .
- my 9 in the numeric keypad was trigger Command 9, so under Karabiner I added an item in the simple modifications tab that disable the right command which was triggered when pressing 9 :  right_command => vk_none(disable this key) .